# R markdown indentation issue

Tags: r, markdown, indentation

I have been searching for the solution for a long time. The indentation changes whenever I add a table in between as you can see in the picture. I am not sure where I did wrong.

```
title: "Markdown_file"
author: "MZ"
date: "10/27/2019"
output: pdf_document
---


1.  abc dd dd 
    (a) adb
    (b) dwd

|    |   A| B |  C | 
|---:|---:|--:|---:|
|a   |  1 | 2 |  3 |
|b   |  1 | 3 |  3 |
|c   |  1 | 3 |  3 |

    (c) ddd
    (d) dddw
```

This is what it looks like when I add a table. As you can see, it is not line up

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a Markdown issue, not particular to RMarkdown, and is answered here:  https://superuser.com/a/1409106.  The idea is that you indent your table, and don't include a blank line after it:

```
---
title: "Markdown_file"
author: "MZ"
date: "10/27/2019"
output: pdf_document
---


1.  abc dd dd 
    (a) adb
    (b) dwd

    |    |   A| B |  C | 
    |---:|---:|--:|---:|
    |a   |  1 | 2 |  3 |
    |b   |  1 | 3 |  3 |
    |c   |  1 | 3 |  3 |
    (c) ddd
    (d) dddw
```